# The li :after do not work

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I use the `li:after` to add content after the `li`, but not work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner {
  height: 30px;
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#banner ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#banner ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#banner ul li :after {
  content: "a";
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>link</li>
      <li>product</li>
      <li>phone</li>
      <li>cat</li>
      <li>about</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Why the contents do not shows ?

Comment: remove the space before the colon - `#banner ul li:after`

Comment: a simple google would've helped you and it would've been much faster than posting a question here. SEARCH and RESEARCH then ask 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: please always do some research before posting a question.. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have this `top: 1px; bottom: 1px; right: 0;` you need  to use `position` and there is a space between `a` and `::after`

with that space,  it would apply `::after` to all children of `li`. So it is the same as

```css
#banner ul li *::after
```

See a Snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner {
  height: 30px;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#banner ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#banner ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}

#banner ul li::after {
  content: "a";
  position:absolute;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>product</li>
    <li>phone</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>about</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why position ? maybe he didn't want it to be at the far right of the li, but right after the text

Comment: because op has this `top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

There should be no space between the element (`li`) and `:after`.

It should be:

```
#banner ul li:after
```

and **not**

```
#banner ul li :after
```

Answer (score -3):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner {
  height: 30px;
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#banner ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#banner ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#banner ul li:after {
  content: "a";
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>link</li>
      <li>product</li>
      <li>phone</li>
      <li>cat</li>
      <li>about</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: no space allowed in between pseudo code and html element while writing the css code